# How can Filter two or more fields in React Js

Tags: reactjs, json, filter, react-hooks

I have 1000 of the following types of objects in an array with a few other properties I didn't mention"

```
{
   "company": "Seattle Sutton",
   "owner": "Gartling",
   "city" "Des Moines"
   "otherproperties": ...
}

{
   "company": "Starbucks",
   "owner": "Schultz",
   "city" "Cleveland"
   "otherproperties": ...
}
```

UI is as follows:

```
 <input onChange={handleChange} type=checkbox value="Seatle Sutton" />
<input onChange={handleChange} type=checkbox value="Starbucks" />
<input onChange={handleChange} type=checkbox value="Caribou" />

 <input onChange={handleChange} type=checkbox value=Gartling" />
<input onChange={handleChange} type=checkbox value="Schultz" />
<input onChange={handleChange} type=checkbox value="Leland" />

 <input onChange={handleChange} type=checkbox value="Des Moines" />
<input onChange={handleChange} type=checkbox value="Cleveland" />
<input onChange={handleChange} type=checkbox value="Tenessee" />
```

My filter is currently in onChangeHandler

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
const value = e.target.value;
const checked = e.target.checked;
if (checked){
    setFieldsSelectedArray([... fieldSelectedArray, value])
}else {
     setFieldSelectedArray(fieldSelectedArray.filter((e)=>(e!== value));
}
}
```

Basically if you click a checkbox, it gets added to fieldSelectedArray, if you deselect a checkbox it gets removed from that array.  Pretty simple.

The filter needs to take this array of all the different fields that have been clicked and then filter the values in the array from the total set of Data.

```
resultSet.filter(function(result){
      return !fieldSelectedArray.includes(result.company);
    }
```

this is fine if there is only one value such as just company or just owner but if I try to filter for 2 or more values there is no way to know whether I have an array of fieldSelectedArray items that has companies only or companies and owners and cities.  Which would mean I would need to have a filter that was possibly

```
resultSet.filter(function(result){
      return !fieldSelectedArray.includes(result.company && result.owner);
    }
```

I'm not sure I am making myself clear but no examples show how to handle a scenario like this. Has anyone crossed an issue like this before.  I have seen it done but the only way I can think of is a long messy way with flags.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, it's basically can be resolved with using **ID as an identifier** for that reason. Somehow you kind of make use of same functionality with company first but, if you tell here it can be more objects containing same company then create and use an ***ID for each of these objects***. Then as a seperate thing you but you can easily create these UI inputs above dynamically from a function as well.

Comment: Erhan not following what you are saying. Could you please try and explain further.  that also would not solve the issue of knowing if you should have an && in the indclude statement

Comment: What about `![result.company, result.owner].some(result => fieldSelectedArray.includes(result))`? You add all your filters to the array as well.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but doesnt some return a boolean? IOneed a new. array

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-ptolemy-pkvdfj?file=/src/App.js:787-845) logging as it works like you wish.

Let's have a **data array** consisting of objects like you shared above. This time it contains differently ***a unique identifier*** for each one of them.

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    company: "Seattle Sutton",
    owner: "Gartling",
    city: "Des Moines",
    otherproperties: "..."
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    company: "Starbucks",
    owner: "Schultz",
    city: "Cleveland",
    otherproperties: "..."
  }
];
```

Apart from declaring same variables and handler function presented with your question above, there's only mapping function `data.map((data) => {` within return statement in order to create checkboxes dynamically for ***each of your objects within data array***.

```
export default function App() {
  const [fieldSelectedArray, setFieldSelectedArray] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const checked = e.target.checked;

    if (checked)
      setFieldSelectedArray([
        ...fieldSelectedArray,
        data.find((element) => value == element.id)
      ]);
    else
      setFieldSelectedArray(
        fieldSelectedArray.filter((element) => element.id !== value)
      );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {data.map((data) => {
        return (
          <>
            <input onChange={handleChange} type="checkbox" value={data.id} />
            <label>{data.company}</label>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then, it's just matter of editing handleChange function declared, as it's matching the needs to fit the same way. In order to match targeting id's with `data` object and `fieldSelectedArray`, It's needed to be sure our checkboxes have their ***id's as their value***, even they represent their ***company name as a label***.

Let me know if you have any other question or explanation on part of it.

Comment: Thank you for your code response.  I am confused with how this would help with the issue I mentioned the actual filter  od results resultSet.filter(function(result){
      return !fieldSelectedArray.includes(result.company && result.owner);
    }

Comment: the array could contain all 3 fields meaning a user selected something from each input. in that case i would need to filter as resultSet.filter(function(result){
      return !fieldSelectedArray.includes(result.company && result.owner);
    }. but what if there is only companies in list and not any owners. this wont work for that scenario.